# how to use $.makeArray() with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, arrays

Can anyone explain me how to do this, jquery's api is really lacking on this. What is wrong in the following code?

```
   var arr = $(value).filter(function() { return $(this).is("TD"); } ).html();
   alert(arr[1]);
```

I just want to grab the innerHTML/text of the td and put it in an array

Comment: What's not working? You're not even calling `$.makeArray()`!

Comment: how would i do it with makeArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.map()` with `.get()` is one way to go:

```
var arr = $(value).map(function() { 
      var $th = $(this); 
      if($th.is("TD")) return $th.html(); 
}).get();

alert(arr);
```

I'm not sure what `value` represents, but if you change the selector to match only `td` elements, you could simplify the return statement with `return $(this).html();`.

`.map()` iterates over the elements, and adds the return value to the jQuery object. `.get()` retrieves just the array out of the jQuery object.

- http://api.jquery.com/map/
- http://api.jquery.com/get/

---

Sounds like `value` is a `tr`. Then you could do this:

```
var arr = $(value).children('td').map(function() { 
      return  $(this).html(); 
}).get();

alert(arr);
```

---

To create an array with each item containing an array of that row's `td` element's html, you could do this:

```
var arr = [];

$('tr').each(function() { 
    arr.push($(this).children('td').map(function() {
        return $(this).html();
    }));
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

This uses the standard `.push()` since I don't think that using `.map()` inside `.map()` would work. I think when you pass the inner array into the jQuery object, it just adds it to the main array (or something).

Comment: arr[0] is true/false and [1] is still undefined. I want a true javascript array as they call it in jquery api. I want to pass that array to the datatable, maybe someone have a better solution?

Comment: @Pierluc - I assume you're referring to my first example before I realized that `value` was a `tr`. Try the second.

Comment: @Pierluc - You're welcome. And yes, the result will be a true js Array. :o)

Comment: let's say there is many tr tags(containing tds of course). Would it be possible, in a similar way, to turn all the trs>tds into a 2dimension array?

Comment: @Pierluc - So you want an array of arrays? I'll update my answer. Give it a try and let me know if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: well what I'm trying to do is more something like arr[0,0] (first indexer would be the tr, and second the td)

Comment: @Pierluc - I'm not too familiar with other languages, but in the example given, you would access the values in a similar manner `arr[0][0]`. I haven't seen that style in javascript. Another option would be using a javascript object I suppose. Then you could access with `obj["0,0"]` I suppose. Or `obj[00]`.

Comment: oh that's exactly what i wanted. That make sens now hehe, I had some intense headache on friday. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `html()` function, and similar functions like `text()` and `width()` return a scalar value for the first matched element.

If you want an array with the HTML contents of every matched element, you should call [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), like this:

```
var arr = $(value).children('td').map(function() { return $(this).html(); }).get();
alert(arr[0]);   //Alerts HTML of first <td> element
```

Comment: Need a `.get()` on the end to get the base array instead of the jQuery wrapped one :)

Comment: @Pierluc - Instead of `.filter()` you need `.children()` or `.find()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

The `.html()` function:

> Description: Get the HTML contents of
>   the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.

This is true of many jQuery functions that are retrieving values.  So what's happening is that your filter function is returning a set of jQuery elements, but your .html() function is causing `arr` to just be assigned the html from the first element in the set.